# Stuck in loading data from database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, oledb, oledbdatareader

In making this appointment calendar, I wanted to use access database to save and retrieve my appointments. However I have more than one property type (Strings, Ints, DateTime) and more than one type of boxes (ComboBox, ListBox, DateTimePicker) to display in the windows forms.
I have managed to write my code for the database with the following code (part of it):

```
foreach(var appointment in listOfAppointments)
{
    OleDbCommand DbCommand = new OleDbCommand(
        "INSERT INTO NewAppointmentDatabase " + 
        "([Start], [Length], [DisplayableDescription], [OccursOnDate], [Location], [IsRecurring], [Frequency], [Occurence]) " + 
        "VALUES(@Start, @Length, @DisplayableDescription, @OccursOnDate, @Location, @IsRecurring, @Frequency, @Occurence)", 
        SaveAppntAccess);

    DbCommand.Connection = SaveAppntAccess;


    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", appointment.Start);  //is a short time in DateTime
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Length", appointment.Length); //is an int
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayableDescription", appointment.DisplayableDescription); //is a long string
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OccursOnDate", appointment.OccursOnDate(date)); //is a boolean with DateTime as argument
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", appointment.Location); //is a string
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsRecurring", appointment.IsRecurring); //is a boolean with yes/no tickbox
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Frequency", appointment.Frequency); //is a string
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurence", appointment.Occurence); //is an int
```

<sub>I have to note that the word date in `appointment.OccursOnDate(date)` is reddened in visual studio which is kind of weird because the boolean parameter is inherited.</sub>

And then comes the tricky part: I want to load my data! But I want to take my values from the database and assign them to each property first, and then take those and display them in the ComboBoxes and TextBoxes and DateTimePickers.

The code goes like this (part of it):

```
if(LoadAppntAccess.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    OleDbCommand DbCommand = new OleDbCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM NewAppointmentDatabase", LoadAppntAccess);
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    DbCommand.Connection = LoadAppntAccess;
    reader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    foreach (var appointment in listofAppointments)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //code to complete
        }
    }
}
```

How will I assign the values from each field to  each property? I was thinking something like this:

```
appointment.Start.Add(reader["Start"].ToString());
appointment.Length.Add((reader["Length"].ToString());
appointment.DisplayableDescription(reader["DisplayableDescritpion"].ToString());
```

But I get errors in all of those - what is the right syntax?

**EDIT** : I forgot to mention that "start" although it's assigned as `DateTime`, I used as a ShortTime value because I wanted a ComboBox with time and 30 minute intervals. So it's not exactly a Date. For `OccursOnDate` it was written as:

```
public bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Date == date;
}
```

and to retrieve a date I used a `DateTimePicker`.

**2nd edit for more info**

My class looks like this:

```
public class Appointment : IAppointment
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string DisplayableDescription { get; set; }
    public bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.Date == date;

    }

    //custom members
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsRecurring { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public int Occurence { get; set; }


    public Appointment()
    {

    }
```

but unfortunately it inherits the parameters from IAppointment which has this code.

```
int ID { get; }

    DateTime Start { get; }
    int Length { get; }
    string DisplayableDescription { get; }
    bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date);

    //custom members
    string Location { get; set; }
    bool IsRecurring { get; set; }
    string Frequency { get; set; }
    int Occurence { get; set; }
```

The custom members are my addition since I had to put some extra stuff according to the specs.

However I managed to find a syntax based on your answers below.

```
appointment.Start.((DateTime)reader["Start"]);
appointment.Length.((int)reader["Length"]);
appointment.DisplayableDescription.((string)reader["DisplayableDescritpion"]);
appointment.OccursOnDate((DateTime)reader["OccursOnDate"]);
appointment.Location.((string)reader["Location"]);
appointment.IsRecurring.((bool)reader["IsRecurring"]);
appointment.Frequency.((string)reader["Frequency"]);
appointment.Occurence.((int)reader["Occurence"]);
```

I still get this message:
[image: Identifier expected]

Any clues?

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing? Can you post them?

Comment: `appointment.Start = ((DateTime)reader["Start"]);` Notice the equal sign **=** between `Start` and `((`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the info you have given i would guess something like this:

```
appointment.Start = (DateTime)reader["Start"];
appointment.Length = (int)reader["Length"];
appointment.DisplayableDescription = (string)reader["DisplayableDescritpion"];
```

This is just a simple example, we would need more info to give a better answer. If any of the columns can have a null value you need to handle that as well etc..

Comment: My parameters are read-only so I could not get this solution to work. And since this is the work of a previous programmer I want to make as few alterations as possible. Please another syntax as Nino's comment above and tell me what you think... It is confusing.

Comment: I you are saying that appointment.Start is readonly then i could see why there is a problem. Could you show us the code for the appointment class if this is the case? Just without knowing anything about the class, if the parameters are readonly there is no way of setting the values, and then there are probably a good reason to why this was blocked. Or there could be a specific way they need to be set, we need more info about the class to know for sure.

Comment: I made a second edit with a bit more info about the classes and the inheritance. Also I altered the syntax and even though it seems ok, I get the identifier expected error

Comment: As @Nino mentioned above you need to use a equal sign as my code above. Your code: appointment.Start.((DateTime)reader["Start"]);    First off you have finished with a . before the (      Start.(  that is not valid. Try the code above and if it does not work then give as en exact error like the error you shown us with identifier expected and perhaps we can help more.

Comment: Apologies people... this was the right syntax and it worked after I changed my IList<IAppointment> in my Load method to List<Appointment>. After a lot of  trial and error, It seems it doesn't make a difference since both the List and Appointment inherit from IList and Interface IAppointment. Thank you again for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

access reader's columns like this, using column index (column index 0 is first column from your `SELECT` clause, 1 is second... etc). As you can see, call reader's right method to get appropriate type of data.

```
appointment.Start = reader.GetDateTime(0);
appointment.Length = reader.GetInt32(1);
appointment.DisplayableDescription= reader.GetString(2);
```

you can also get data by specifiying column name.

```
appointment.Start = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Start"));
        appointment.Length = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Length"));
        appointment.DisplayableDescription = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DisplayableDescritpion"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the two worked. But I found another syntax which is this:
appointment.Start.((DateTime)reader["Start"]);
appointment.Length.((int)reader["Length"]);
even though it seems correct, before the first parenthesis, I get an error "identifier expected"... why do I get this?

Comment: use like this `appointment.Start = ((DateTime)reader["Start"])`. btw, in my first answer, I made a mistake, but later I have edited the code. Maybe you tried with that wrong version. But, this solution that @FSDaniel wrote should also work.

Comment: It didn't work either... I found a syntax though which I show in my second edit. Please have a look.

Comment: oh, come on... read the answers. Use `=` sign for assignment, not `.`

Answer (score 0):

I posted in a comment but since it wasn't made clear with no picture I am posting now my previous try that didn't work and explain.

This is the code mentioned both by @Nino and @FsDaniel

[image: The error]

If you see the Interface's parameters (in my initial post), they only have the get property which makes Start, Length and DisplaybleDescritption readonly. Thus the error. The rest is ok because they are my custom members and I gave them get and set properties. I do not wish to make any alterations in the Interface, that's why I am asking to find if there can be another solution.